# Is this an error in Typescript compiler

Tags: typescript2.0

I noticed an issue where a user defined typeguard on a union type doesn't behave symmetrically. I hope this an error on my end :-/

The issue shows up in `test2()` where the type is not inferred properly from the typeguard.

```
class PropPacket {
    constructor(public key: string, public value: number) {}
}

class EventPacket {
    constructor(public key: string) {}
}

type Packet = PropPacket | EventPacket;

function isPropPacket(p: EventPacket | PropPacket): p is PropPacket {
    return p instanceof PropPacket;
}

function isEventPacket(p: EventPacket | PropPacket): p is EventPacket {
    return p instanceof EventPacket;
}

function test1(p: Packet) {
    if (isPropPacket(p)) {
        // `p` is PropPacket
        p.key;
        p.value;
    } else {
        // `p` is EventPacket
        p.key;
    }
}

function test2(p: Packet) {
    if (isEventPacket(p)) {
        p.key;
    } else {
        // ERROR: thinks `p` is `never` type
        p.key;
        p.value;
    }
}
```

You can see the issue by pasting the code in the typescript playground (https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)

Comment: Interesting. I am not a language lawyer, but for what it's worth, it behaves like you'd expect it to if you rename the `key` property in either of the `Packet` types to something else, e.g. `key2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because all `EventPacket`s are in fact `PropertyPacket`s. Typescript has a structural type system which does not consider two classes to be distinct by declaration, only by the properties and methods they contain.

Comment: Hmmm - looks like you're right. If I add an unused private property to the EventPacket declaration it solves the issue. Guess that is an ugly side-effect of the system.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is necessarily a bad thing. On the one hand, it doesn't match the runtime behavior (bad), on the other it discourages this sort of code (good).